# Double comparison and replacing

Tags: r, replace, compare, conditional-statements

I have a problem. I need to replace TWO columns if they meet two conditions:

1. Two columns which I want to compare from data must be equal (in pairs in the same row).
2. Two columns must be equal to 7 or 8 or 9.

If the conditions have been met, R should replace TWO columns for NA.

E.g.:
Suppose that I want to compare the second and third columns from my data:

```
data[,2] = 7,2,4,5,9,2,1,8,2,4
data[,3] = 3,2,5,6,9,3,1,8,2,4
```

And in result I would like to receive it:

```
data[,2] = 7,2,4,5,NA,2,1,NA,2,4
data[,3] = 3,2,5,6,NA,3,1,NA,2,4
```

R should compare for NA both columns when they are equal and are equal to `{7 or 8 or 9}.`

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work? SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a logical index based on the two columns

```
i1 <- data[,2]==data[,3] & data[,2] %in% 7:9 & data[,3] %in% 7:9
data[i1, 2:3] <- NA
```

---

Or with `Reduce` and `&`

```
data[Reduce(`&`, lapply(data[2:3], `%in%`, 7:9)), 2:3] <- NA
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(col1 = 1:10, col2 = c(7, 2, 4, 5, 9, 2, 1, 8, 
2, 4), col3 = c(3, 2, 5, 6, 9, 3, 1, 8, 2, 4)), .Names = c("col1", 
 "col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you, but if one columns have 7 and second 8 in the same row It can't replacing. If I want to compare other values (not 7:9 e.g. 1,4,8) Should I create a vector? c(1,4,8)? Thank you.

Comment: @BartekCzech  In the first approach, that was taken care of by `data[,2]==data[,3]`.  In second , it is the `Reduce("&"`, that checks whether they are both TRUEs.  If you want to compare c(1,4,8) use that instead of 7:9, i.e. `Reduce("&", lapply(data[2:3], "%in%, c(1,4,8))`